# How to fix 'Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined'

Tags: javascript

This is for a navigation header and it works, but I still get an error on line 2. VM4582 header.js:2 Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined 
I don't understand why it says $(window) is not defined.

```
// Sticky Header
$(window).scroll(function() {

    if ($(window).scrollTop() > 100) {
        $('.main_h').addClass('sticky');
    } else {
        $('.main_h').removeClass('sticky');
    }
});

// Mobile Navigation
$('.mobile-toggle').click(function() {
    if ($('.main_h').hasClass('open-nav')) {
        $('.main_h').removeClass('open-nav');
    } else {
        $('.main_h').addClass('open-nav');
    }
});

$('.main_h li a').click(function() {
    if ($('.main_h').hasClass('open-nav')) {
        $('.navigation').removeClass('open-nav');
        $('.main_h').removeClass('open-nav');
    }
});

// navigation scroll lijepo radi materem
$('nav a').click(function(event) {
    var id = $(this).attr("href");
    var offset = 70;
    var target = $(id).offset().top - offset;
    $('html, body').animate({
        scrollTop: target
    }, 500);
    event.preventDefault();
});
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour] (you get a badge!), have a look around, and read through the [help], in particular [*How do I ask a good question?*](/help/how-to-ask) I also recommend Jon Skeet's [Writing the Perfect Question](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/). Please [**search**](/search?q=Uncaught+ReferenceError%3A+%24+is+not+defined) before posting. More on searching [here](/help/searching).

Answer (score 0):

If you are using $ then you are dealing with jQuery and this error will occure when you dont add jQuery cdn or jquery reference script file so kindly check the jQuery cdn and paste it in your head section and this will solve your problem.